# Java: read input xml and write output xml with some updated attribute values

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I have to read a big xml file (`A.xml`) and create a new xml file (`B.xml`) with the same content as `A.xml` except for some attribute values that need to be updated in `B.xml`.
For example if `A.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<one>
    <!-- comment -->
    <a att="hello" />
</one>
<two />
```

I want `B.xml` to contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<one>
    <!-- comment -->
    <a att="UPDATED" />
</one>
<two />
```

I was looking at [one solution](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/DuplicatesXMLFiles.htm) that uses SAX for parsing and a `PrintWriter` for writing, but it looks quite low level and I don't know if it is possible to copy comments and keep this type of close tags: `/>`.
I'd prefer a streaming parser rather than loading the whole document in memory but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a streaming solution you can use a `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader` or `XMLEventReader` to read the XML document, update any parts that you want to change, and pipe the data/events from the reader into a `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter` or `XMLEventWriter`.

Comment: Thanks I think `XMLEventWriter` doesn't have a way to write self closing tags so I'll probably go with the  `XMLStreamWriter`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason as to why you're unhappy with keeping the xml document in memory, unless the xml files you're working with are large (100+ MB).

There are two ways I can think of to solve this:

1. Read the file character by character and change what needs changing. This fits what you're asking, but it's slow and hard to implement.
2. Use an xml parser, find the elements you're looking for and change them. I'm leaning towards this.

The first way involves reading the xml file character by character, finding the tag(s) you're looking for, changing them and writing the xml to the second file as you're doing this. This is quite stream-lined, but, it xml can contain tags within tags so that can get complicated really fast. You could achieve this with a parser, but that will probably involve keeping the document in memory.

The second is simple. Use an xml parser to parse the file, iterate over the elements, change them, and finally, write the edited xml back to file. This involves keeping the document in memory, but unless you're on a memory constrained computer or the document is huge(100+ MB), this isn't really a problem.

I'm not going to write out a complete program here, nor will I give an example of the first way (It's too complicated to post to SO anyway), I will give you a starting point for the second way though.

**What you're here for:**

*Written with Java 8 update 65*

*Requires the library: [Dom4J](https://dom4j.github.io/) for xml parser.*

```
public class Main {

    private static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * The file we're reading from.
     */
    private File inputFile;

    /**
     * The file we're writing to.
     */
    private File outputFile;

    /**
     * The attributes to replace.
     */
    private List<UserAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

    private Main() {
        getFiles();
        getReplacementTags();
    }

    private void getFiles() {
        System.out.println("Please enter the input file...");
        String input = SCANNER.nextLine();

        File inFile = new File(input);

        if (!inFile.exists() || !inFile.isFile()) {
            System.err.println("The file you entered doesn't exits or isn't a file!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        inputFile = inFile;

        System.out.println("Please enter the output file...");
        String output = SCANNER.nextLine();

        File outFile = new File(output);

        if (!outFile.exists()) {
            try {
                outFile.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("Created file: " + outFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't create the output file!");
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }

        outputFile = outFile;
    }

    private void getReplacementTags() {
        System.out.println("Enter the tags you wish to replace");
        System.out.println("The format is &element name &attribute &replacement. (e.g. &one &a att &UPDATED!)");
        System.out.println("Enter a list of tags you wish to replace with each in a new line. Enter # when finished.");

        while (true) {//I'm using an infinate loop because it just seams easier to implement.
            String line = SCANNER.nextLine();

            if (line.equals("#")) {
                break;
            }

            try {
                UserAttribute attribute = getAttributeFromUserText(line);
                this.attributes.add(attribute);
                System.out.println("Added attribute replacement: " + attribute);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect attribute format: \n\t" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        startReplacing();
    }

    private void startReplacing() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = new SAXReader().read(inputFile);
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            System.err.println("Coundn't read xml file: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(3);
        }

        replaceAttributes(doc);

        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile)) {
            doc.write(writer);
            System.out.println("Saved xml document to file: " + outputFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't write to file: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This does all the magic.
     *
     * You might want to fix this up as I'm sure it's rather slow. This only
     * scans 1 tag deep.
     */
    private void replaceAttributes(Document doc) {
        for (UserAttribute uattribute : attributes) {
            Element root = doc.getRootElement();

            for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                Element element = (Element) i.next();

                if (element.getName().equals(uattribute.element)) {
                    for (Iterator i1 = element.attributeIterator(); i1.hasNext();) {
                        Attribute attribute = (Attribute) i1.next();

                        if(attribute.getName().equals(uattribute.attribute)){
                            attribute.setValue(uattribute.replacement);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }

    private static UserAttribute getAttributeFromUserText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {//This is a bit incomplete...
        String[] split = text.split("&");

        if (split.length != 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect number of arguments!");
        }

        return new UserAttribute(split[1].replace(" ", ""), split[2].replace(" ", ""), split[3]);
    }

    private static final class UserAttribute {

        public final String element;

        public final String attribute;

        public final String replacement;

        public UserAttribute(String element, String attribute, String replacement) {
            this.element = element;
            this.attribute = attribute;
            this.replacement = replacement;
        }

        public String getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public String getAttribute() {
            return attribute;
        }

        public String getReplacement() {
            return replacement;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{element=%s, attribute=%s, replacement=%s}", element, attribute, replacement);
        }
    }
}
```

A.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <PersonA name="Jenny" age="22">
        <!-- A Random Comment -->
        <friends number="3">
        Friend A,
        Friend B,
        Friend C
        </friends>
    </PersonA>

    <PersonB name="Bob" age="44">
        <!-- A Random Comment... again -->
        <friends number="5">
        Friend A,
        Friend B,
        Friend C,
        Friend D,
        Friend E
        </friends>
    </PersonB>
</root>
```

B.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <PersonA name="Joe" age="41">
        <!-- A Random Comment -->
        <friends number="3">
        Friend A,
        Friend B,
        Friend C
        </friends>
    </PersonA>

    <PersonB name="Ashley" age="32">
        <!-- A Random Comment... again -->
        <friends number="5">
        Friend A,
        Friend B,
        Friend C,
        Friend D,
        Friend E
        </friends>
    </PersonB>
</root>
```

Arguments

```
run:
Please enter the input file...
A.xml
Please enter the output file...
B.xml
Enter the tags you wish to replace
The format is &element name &attribute &replacement. (e.g. &one &a att &UPDATED!)
Enter a list of tags you wish to replace with each in a new line. Enter # when finished.
&PersonA &name &Joe
Added attribute replacement: {element=PersonA, attribute=name, replacement=Joe}
&PersonA &age &41
Added attribute replacement: {element=PersonA, attribute=age, replacement=41}
&PersonB &name &Ashley
Added attribute replacement: {element=PersonB, attribute=name, replacement=Ashley}
&PersonB &age &32
Added attribute replacement: {element=PersonB, attribute=age, replacement=32}
#
Saved xml document to file: B.xml
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 32 seconds)
```

This does almost everything you're asking for, the only problems are:

1. It's a bit slow as it has to scan every element and so on.
2. It only scans the top level elements (i.e. the friends tags won't be scaned)
3. It's very basic

Although problems aside, this should give you a head start... I hope.

P.S. Sorry for any spelling mistakes, bigs, incorrect formatting. I did write this in a short time without doing too much testing. Comment if you find something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm more inclined to use any of the reader/writers suggested by @wero

Answer (score 1):

The best XML parser for your update use case is undoutably [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)... for the follow 2 reasons:

1. It is far more memory efficient than DOM... 1.3x ~ 1.5x for vtd-xml
   compared to 3x~5x for DOM
2. It supports incremental update, which is unique among all XML parsing lib available.. Basically, you will only need to cut out the original attribute value "hello" and then replace it with "UPDATE." No other part of the document is touched...

Read [this paper](https://recipp.ipp.pt/bitstream/10400.22/1847/1/ART_BrunoOliveira_2013.pdf) for further information: It is entitled "***Processing XML with Java – A Performance Benchmark***".